# Eliminate duplicate from a mysql database query

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem in writing a MySQL query from my table INVOICES
I have 1 line per item purchased (ID, Date, Time, First, Last_Name, ITEM_PURCH, PRICE)

I would like to use this table to extract the customers who came into the shop.
For example, I have Zoe MARTIN who purchased 2 items the same day
Also, Cammille VELAZQUEZ who also purchase 2 items the same day
I would like to be able to SELECT with the question: PLEASE SORT THE CUSTOMERS LIST WHO CAME in the 30/01/2019 regardless the number of products purchased

With a result like this

```
46681   30/01/2019  09:09:24    Zoe MARTIN
46685   30/01/2019  09:39:08    Carmen  SMITH
46686   30/01/2019  09:58:14    Valery  SIMON
46689   30/01/2019  10:17:11    Camille VELAZQUEZ
46691   30/01/2019  10:24:30    Alexia  SERR
46694   30/01/2019  10:49:40    Olivia  ANABEL
46697   30/01/2019  11:13:18    Jennifer    JOGHIN
```

Eliminating the MARTIN duplicate and the VELAZQUEZ

Original table with 2 duplicates

```
ID  Date    Time    First   Last_Name   ITEM PURCH  Price
46681   30/01/2019  09:09:24    Zoe MARTIN  First purchase  175.00
46682   30/01/2019  09:09:57    Zoe MARTIN  New proetct 175.00
46685   30/01/2019  09:39:08    Carmen  SMITH   Product 1   104.17
46686   30/01/2019  09:58:14    Valery  SIMON   Product 3   145.83
46689   30/01/2019  10:17:11    Camille VELAZQUEZ   Product1    104.17
46690   30/01/2019  10:17:25    Camille VELAZQUEZ   Product2    104.17
46691   30/01/2019  10:24:30    Alexia  SERR    Product 555 129.17
46694   30/01/2019  10:49:40    Olivia  ANABEL  Product 23  33.33
46697   30/01/2019  11:13:18    Jennifer    JOGHIN  Product 345 250.00
```

ANy help with building the table would be fantastic

I'm giving more information about this question.
I need to delete the duplicate lines of a customer came twice or more during the same day. But I want to keep the lines if the customer has come yesterday or one month ago (just removing the duplicates each day he came).

I would like to ask MySQL
"please make a list of customers who came at least once a day in the shop, from what you have in the invoice table" - I only need 1 line per customer per day (even if he purchased 2 or 3 items).

I want to be able to say:
From the beginning of this database until now, I got XXX different costumers who bought at least 1 thing. And here is the list of their names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select a.ID, a.Date, a.Time, a.First, a.Last_Name from invoices a join ( select id,Date,concat(First, Last_Name) as fullname from INVOICES group by Date,fullname  ) b on a.id=b.id;
```

Comment: Does not seem to work.   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by fullname from INVOICE ) b on a.id =b.id 
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1 . I rechecked the table names and column names

Comment: I tested. no error. But it seems to delete more lines than expected. Mabe the 'concat' need to be refined

Comment: I have a field called id_customer in each line of the table (unique id_customer per first_name and last_name). Can this help ?

Comment: I made some minor mods with id_customer and I think it is perfect. select a.id_quote, a.date_in, a.time_in, a.firstname, a.lastname from invoice a join ( select id_quote,date_in,concat(id_customer) as fullname from invoice  group by date_in,fullname ) b on a.id_quote=b.id_quote order by date_in,time_in  . Thanks

Comment: great.. also you can remove concat since there is only one field inside concat